# deploy a directory in a Extjs 5 package

Tags: extjs, package

I'm using Extjs5, its package system and Sencha Cmd.

I wrote a package and I added a new source directory ("foosrc") besides the traditional "src" directory :

```
myapp/
  |
  packages/
    |
    foopackage/
      |
      src/
      |
      foosrc/
```

Now, when I build myapp (with `sencha app build`), I would like that `foosrc` to be embedded into the production build directory, something like that:

```
myapp/
  |
  build/
    |
    production/
      |
      MyApp
        |
        **packages**
          | 
          **foopackage**
            |
            **foosrc**
```

I don't really understand what variable in what file I must change to get this configuration...
The goal of all this is that all source files in "foosrc" will be dynamically loaded in production, using some "Ext.Loader.setPath" calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Sencha packages.
But I am sure that in a standard ExtJS app generated by Sencha cmd, you can add custom source directories by updating the “**classpath**” in app.json.
Once the classpath is updated, then next **sencha app build** will include source files in the custom directories to the app.js in production build.

Comment: Yes, it works with an app. But when I add "foosrc" to the classpath of a package.json, and I "sencha app build" again, the production build app.js does contain the files I put in foosrc.... and yet, it works in development mode (with no concatenation), my files in "foosrc" are in the application bootstrap.json!